# $twig->purge is giving empty file

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I may be asking a basic question but it's killing me.

Following is my code snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;


my $twig = new XML::Twig( twig_handlers => { TRADE => \&TRADE } );

$twig->parsefile('1510.xml');

$twig->set_pretty_print('indented');

$twig->print_to_file('out.xml');

sub TRADE {
    my ( $twig, $TRADE ) = @_;
    #added delete in place of cut
     $TRADE->cut($TRADE) unless
     $TRADE->att('origin') eq "COMPUTER";
}
```

This is working as expected. It is giving me all TRADES having 'origin' equals 'COMPUTER'.

But I need to handle XML files spanning to 1 GB.
In that case it 'segmentation error' as it consumes huge memory.

Hence, in order to resolve the issue I am trying to implement 'purge' concept of XML::Twig

Hence I modified the code to :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use XML::Twig;


    my $twig = new XML::Twig( twig_handlers => { TRADE => \&TRADE } );

    $twig->parsefile('1510.xml');

    $twig->set_pretty_print('indented');

    $twig->print_to_file('out.xml');

    sub TRADE {
        my ( $twig, $TRADE ) = @_;
        #added delete in place of cut
         $TRADE->cut($TRADE) unless
         $TRADE->att('origin') eq "COMPUTER";

         $twig->purge; 
    }
```

This is giving me empty file. I am trying to flush those twigs which are used in order to use memory efficiently.

I don't know why it is giving me blank output file.

Sample XML :

```
<TRADEEXT>
 <TRADE origin = 'COMPUTER'/>
 <TRADE origin = 'COMP'/>
 <TRADE origin = 'COMPP'/>  
</TRADEEXT>
```

output file:

```
<TRADEEXT>
 <TRADE origin = 'COMPUTER'/>
</TRADEEXT>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably use `flush` (to a filehandle) instead of `purge`: `flush` outputs the twig that has been parsed so far and frees the memory, while `purge` only frees the memory.

That said, if all you want is to remove the `TRADE` elements that don't have the proper attribute, you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

open( my $out, '>:utf8', "out.xml") or die "cannot create output file out.xml: $!";

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented',
                           twig_roots => { 'TRADE[@origin != "COMPUTER"]' 
                                              => sub { $_->delete; } 
                                         },
                           twig_print_outside_roots => $out,
                         )
                            
                    ->parsefile('1510.xml');
```

This will leave some extra empty lines in the file, you can remove them later. The `twig_roots` handler is triggered for all elements you need to remove, and it deletes them, while the `twig_print_outside_roots` option causes all other elements to be printed as_is.

Comment: great insight. But my requirement is that the original file should remain untouched. The output file should have all legitimate TRADES. Can you please advise. Also, i don;t want any output to be reflected on screen. That's why I used PURGE.

Comment: I think that's what the code I posted does. Did you try it?

Comment: your code is giving right output. Sorry for being novice. But can you please tell me why my purge is not working. Please.

Comment: from the docs, `purge`: *...deletes all elements that have been completely parsed so far.* so all the TRADE elements that you have kept are purged from the memory. You really need to use `flush`, likely to a filehandle, if you want to output the TRADE elements that you want to keep.

Comment: One question, If I need to add one more condition at twig_roots level...How can I do? For example apart from the origin not equal to COMPUTER which is mentioned above, say there is one more condition that <event> tag which is inside <TRADE> tag should have some specific attribute value. Then how to do that??

Comment: you want to delete only the `TRADE` elements that include an `event` element with a specific attribute vallue? The in the handler do `if( $_->descendants( 'event[@att="val"]') { $_->delete; } else { $_->flush( $out); }`